# Xamarin Forms Biometric Face Recognition for Android

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, biometrics

I want to include a biometric login system in my app to allow the user to login using their face, similar to how you can login on iPhone with FaceID. I'm using the Plugin.Fingerprint NuGet package to achieve this. While I am able to get it to work with fingerprints on Android  I cannot seem to have it use face recognition on Android whereas on iOS it will bring up a prompt for FaceID

Am I missing a permission or is it just not possible to achieve this on android?

The code below:

```
public async void BiometricClicked()
    {
        if (!bioOn)
        {
            var request = new AuthenticationRequestConfiguration("Biometric Setup.", "Setup Biometric Login");
            var result = await CrossFingerprint.Current.AuthenticateAsync(request);

            if (result.Authenticated)
            {
                bioOn = true;
                Preferences.Set("BioLogin", DealerName);
                Preferences.Set("BioPass", dealerPass);
                Preferences.Set("BioOn", bioOn);
                UserDialogs.Instance.Alert("Biometric Login successfully activated.", "Biometric", "Ok");

            }
            else
            {
                UserDialogs.Instance.Alert("Cannot setup biometric.", "Biometric", "Ok");
                
            }
        }
        else
        {
            var prompt = await UserDialogs.Instance.ConfirmAsync("Do you wish to turn off biometric login?", "Biometric", "Yes", "No");
            if (prompt)
            {
                Preferences.Remove("BioLogin");
                Preferences.Remove("BioPass");
                bioOn = false;
                Preferences.Set("BioOn", bioOn);
                UserDialogs.Instance.Alert("Biometric login deactivated.", "Biometric", "Ok");
            }
        }

    }
```

The permissions in the Android.manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_FINGERPRINT" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_BIOMETRIC" />
```

The MainActivity.cs:

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        
        
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        
        
        CrossFingerprint.SetCurrentActivityResolver(() => Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.CurrentActivity);
       
        Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
      
        LoadApplication(new App());

    }
```

Comment: "does not work" is not a helpful description of the problem.  Does it crash, throw an exception or an error?  Does the auth UI appear at all?  Have you stepped through the code in the debugger?  Have you checked the log for useful messages?  Have you followed all the steps outlined in the docs?  Have you reviewed the open issues in the plugin repo for similar problems?

Comment: Instead of displaying a prompt to scan the user's face it immediately shows the pop-up "Cannot setup biometric."

Comment: Just to further clarify when tested on a simulator with fingerprint recognition enabled we are able to enable biometric login but on a device with only face recognition available the app gives out the error popup. 

According to the plugin description it should be able to detect face recognition as well as it recognizes FaceID on iOS

Comment: try writing this code "CrossFingerprint.SetCurrentActivityResolver(() => CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Activity);" inside onCreate() in mainActivity.cs file

Comment: I already have CrossFingerprint.SetCurrentActivityResolver(() => Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.CurrentActivity); written inside onCreate() in MainActivity.cs. While it is able to work with fingerprint biometric it doesn't seem to work with face biometric

Comment: Is it possible that the Plugin.Fingerprint NuGet package does not support Face Unlock for Android? I have checked the error logs there but there isn't an answer that solves the issue there.

Comment: When tested on the Android simulator CrossFingerprint.Current.GetAuthenticationTypeAsync returned Fingerprint whereas on the actual device a Samsung Galaxy Note it returned None even though face recognition was set up on the device.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to enable Face Unlock on a Samsung Galaxy Note 8 by having both fingerprint and face recognition registered and then setting the preferred biometric to Face Recognition